# WebMock stub data from Aws CognitoIdentityProvider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, webmock

I have the following module in a Rails controller concern:

```
module AwsAuth
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  require 'aws-sdk'

  def get_cognito_user(token)
    cognitoidentityprovider = Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])

    begin
      cognito_user = cognitoidentityprovider.get_user({ access_token: token })

      puts cognito_user

      return {"email" => cognito_user.username}

    rescue StandardError => msg
      puts "ERROR!"
      puts msg
      return {"error" => msg}
    end
  end
end
```

At the moment, puts cognito_user returns:

```
#<Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Types::GetUserResponse:0x7fe51b0013a8
    mfa_options = nil,
    user_attributes = nil,
    username = nil
>
```

How can I stud the response in Rspec so that username and user_attributes are not nil ?

Comment: Try `allow(cognitoidentityprovider).to receive(:get_user).with(your_params).and_return(your_object)`. Check out [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs)

Comment: Actually, you should show your `rspec` file with the tests for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

after playing around with yzalavin's suggestion... the following works for me...

```
allow_any_instance_of( AwsAuth )
      .to receive(:get_cognito_user)
      .and_return( JSON[ {email: "testy@example.com"}.to_json ] )
```